Handle file downloading in browser
I've some problems with downloading a file in the browser
My question is this:
How can we prevent downloads in a browser if the machine lacks enough memory? (JavaScript solution)
Is it possible to handle it with JavaScript or not?
Do you know any solution in JavaScript for this problem?

Do you mean RAM? or storage on device?

No differences, both of them, I wanna prevent the download process if the machine does not have enough space, either memory or disk.



Is it possible to handle it with JavaScript or not?


No.. as it should be. Javascript doesn't know/access your memory system details.

Do you mean the browser doesn't know/access the system's memory?

That's correct. That's security issue. Imagine someone on internet accessing your files from your computer.
